# How to get the data back from the UITextField?

Tags: objective-c

I have a textfield to type the username, how will i get back the data to perform some action from the UITextField?

Answer (score 0):

UITextField store data as NSString in **text** property:

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *text;

e.g:

```
NSLog(@"my text: %@", muTextField.text);
```

if you want to handle text changes while user edits text use delegate method:

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Comment: Or if you just care about the final value (and not each change as the user makes it), you can use the delegate method:

    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField